# Notepad++ regex find results in XML that does not match a certain value

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to search from the point of a certain parent tag inside the XML and see if a child tag inside 
 this parent tag does not have a certain value. For example you have this:

```
<situation xsi:type="..." id="TYU_A3213132343">
        ....
        <probability>likely</probability>
        .....
</situation>
```

If I want to search this with this value by probability I can use this:

```
<situation xsi:type="([^\"]*)\" id="TYU_A(?:(?!</situation>).)+<probability>likely</probability>
```

But I want to change this regex so it find things like this:

```
<situation xsi:type="..." id="TYU_A3213132343">
        ....
        <probability>randomvalue</probability>
        .....
</situation>
```

So I am searching for the results that does not match the probability with the value likely. Does someone know what needs to be changed about the regex above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `likely` with `(?:(?!likely)(?!</probability>).)+` that matches everything that is not `likely` before it reaches `</probability>`:

```
<situation xsi:type="([^\"]*)\" id="TYU_A(?:(?!</situation>).)+<probability>(?:(?!likely)(?!</probability>).)+</probability>
```

Comment: I want to search the values that does not have the value likely in it

Comment: Oh in some files it will select the whole document instead of searching for it while in other files it works as it should. Do you maybe know what the cause of this can be?

Comment: @MrAndre: Could you give an example that didn't work?

Comment: Seems like it is a bug on notepad++ side with big files... will have to look for a different editor